# Reasons firmware checksums are wrong

Tags: security, uefi, firmware, fwupdmgr

What are the possible reasons that running `fwupdmgr verify` fails?

```
$ fwupdmgr verify 230c8b18-8d9b-53ec-838b-6cfc0383493a
Reading…                 [-                                      ]Selected device: Lite (bios)
Reading…                 [                   -                   ]failed to verify Lite (bios): For Lite (bios) 8.20 expected 73f0b38cbd5fdc45cb259bead04b00413e162328|a22b9f14078b406efc4442a21be1ad8cbfc6ef6c3bd3e6440c651129fd555df7, got 9e365aa2206158c8e7fa09b538d1166c5e522acd|5bd6570571bd28fd54bf5a28b2cd4e561002cfcd1a5b7d16a43767ec273f327f
```

Is it safe to execute `fwupdmgr verify-update` to "accept" the mismatching checksums? Why would they not match in the first place?

Answer (score 1):

Well, the hash of the firmware as read from the device's memory is not as specified; the image that was downloaded and the image read from the flash differ.

Something went wrong during writing, during storage, or during reading.

> Is it safe to execute fwupdmgr verify-update to "accept" the mismatching checksums?

Probably not. These checksums are checked for a reason, namely that it's kind of important your firmware is functional.